# How can I use resources like pictures and text files when I have BlueJ as my IDE?

Tags: java, resources, bluej

I want to use things like text files and png files by using BlueJ. I also want it to work on a computer which does not have the resources.

How to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please narrow down the scope of answer. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways to use external resources and to ensure they are accessible from another computer.

I'm not familiar with BlueJ but if its like most other IDEs...

For code that you write and run in BlueJ you should be able to put the resources next to the compiled .java files.

Say the resource you placed there was called "img.png" and the class containing your main method was called "Main.class".
To load this file as a BufferedImage you would do the following:

```
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(Main.class.getResourcesAsStream("img.png"));
```

This will load the file based on its location relative to your main class file.

If you want this file to be accessible to someone running your program on a different computer the best option is to bundle it with you code into a .jar file. See [THIS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html) for instructions on how to create a jar.

That will show you how to bundle your code into a jar next you have to add the resources (the "img.png" file). To do this download [Jar Splice](http://ninjacave.com/jarsplice) and follow the on screen instructions, its a very simple program to use.

The output from Jar Splice will be a .jar file containing your code and your resources which can be run on any computer with java installed.